# How do I get an element from an HTML table that has an always changing child element number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to collect the total number of hours that I worked from each pay period that I worked. I can collect the total number of hours from the "Grand Totals" section, however it seems like that section never has a static child element number and shares class names with another row.

Here is an example:

from the first page, if I copy selector in Chrome, I get:

```
#TableTimeCard > tbody > tr:nth-child(12) > td:nth-child(3)
```

However, when I go to the next pay period, I get:

```
#TableTimeCard > tbody > tr:nth-child(14) > td:nth-child(3)
```

That "tr:nth-child" number ranges between 4 and however many number of entries I had on my time card.

Here is the snippet of code from the site. I am trying to take in 10.37:

[image: Page screenshot]

I've tried grabbing it by that class name but then it just grabs the first number after "Total Hours" in the image. In this case, 0.00. I believe the reason why is because it has the same class name:

[image: screenshot 2]

All I need to do is print grand total hours to console. Any ideas?

I am doing `print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#TableTimeCard > tbody > tr:nth-child(12) > td:nth-child(3)")`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use `find_elements`  to store all of them, and can iterate like this :-

```
hours = find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#TableTimeCard > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(3)")
print(hours[0].text)
```

or even you can iterate that list as well :-

```
for hour in find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#TableTimeCard > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(3)"):
    print(hour.text)
```

**Update 1 :**

In case if you just want to grab **Total hours** value, use this **xpath** :-

```
//td[text()='Grand Totals']/following-sibling::td[4]
```

**in code :**

```
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[text()='Grand Totals']/following-sibling::td[4]").text)
```

Comment: It ran this time but now it's just adding blank lines to the console. How would i possibly use the Grand Totals text to grab the value from two elements below? Would that be a viable option?

Comment: Can I have the Page url ?

Comment: Since this is my time card, it would be locked behind a login from my employer. The site is from iSolved. time.myisolved.com

Comment: okay, How about this ? You need to save the source code into a text file using `driver.page_resource`, then upload that text file using file sharing website (free ofcourse). they will give you a sharable link. That link you can give me.

Comment: Removed private info and pasted here: https://pastebin.com/1SuSpihU